# python - read file into dictionary - delimited with curly brackets, no comma delimiter

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I'm new to python (pandas, numPy, etc.).
I'd like to know the perfect approach to solve this task in the best and performant way.

I have a huge file that has the following format - expect everything is in one line:

```
{"order_reference":"0658-2147","billing_address_zip_code":"8800"}
{"order_reference":"0453-2200","billing_address_zip_code":"8400"}
{"order_reference":"0554-3027","billing_address_zip_code":"8820"}
{"order_reference":"0382-3108","billing_address_zip_code":"3125"}
{"order_reference":"0534-4059","billing_address_zip_code":"3775"}
{"order_reference":"0118-1566","billing_address_zip_code":"3072"}
{"order_reference":"0384-6897","billing_address_zip_code":"8630"}
{"order_reference":"0361-5226","billing_address_zip_code":"4716"}
{"order_reference":"0313-6812","billing_address_zip_code":"9532"}
{"order_reference":"0344-6262","billing_address_zip_code":"3600"}
```

What is the easiest way to read this file into a dictionary in python or dataFrame in numPy? The goal is to join the billing_address_zip_code to a big JSON file to get more insights of the order_reference.

- I was thinking to solve it with regExp, but as the file is huge, and need to join to another file, I think I should use Pandas, shouldn't I?
- Or as all datasets are the same length, I could also insert by length

Is there a function for that to use pandas? I guess this would be the fastest way, but as it isn't standard JSON, I don't know how to do it.

I'm sorry for the beginner questions, but I search quite a bit on the internet and couldn't find the right answer. And it would really help me to figure out the right approach to this kind of tasks.
For any help or links, I'm very thankful.
Simon

PS: Which cloud environment do you use for this kind of tasks? Which works best with python and the data science libraries?

**UPDATE**

I used the following code to format into a valid JSON and loaded it with json.loads() successfully:

```
#syntay: python 3
import json

#small test file
my_list = "["+open("orders_play_around.json").read().replace("}{","},\n{")+"]"

d = json.loads(my_list)
```

So far so good. Now the next challenge, how do I join this json dictionary with another JSON file that has a join on the *billing_address_zip_code*?
The other JSON looks like this:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "BFS-Nr": 1,
  "Raum mit städtischem Charakter 2012": 4,
  "Typologie der MS-Regionen 2000 (2)": 3,
  "E": 679435,
  "Zusatzziffer": 0,
  "Agglomerationsgrössenklasse 2012": 1,
  "Gemeinde-typen (9 Typen) 2000 (1)": 4,
  "N": 235653,
  "Stadt/Land-Typologie 2012": 3,
  "Städte 2012": 0,
  "Gemeinde-Grössenklasse 2015": 7,
  "BFS Nr.": 1,
  "Sprachgebiete 2016": 1,
  "Europäsiche Berggebietsregionen (2)": 1,
  "Gemeindename_1": "Aeugst am Albis",
  "Anwendungsgebiete für Steuerer-leichterungen 2016": 0,
  "Kantonskürzel": "ZH",
  "Kanton": 1,
  "Metropolräume 2000 (2)": 1,
  "PLZ": 8914,
  "Bezirk": 101,
  "Gemeindetypologie 2012\n(25 Typen)": 237,
  "Raumplanungs-regionen": 105,
  "Gemeindetypologie 2012\n(9 Typen)": 23,
  "Agglomerationen und Kerne ausserhalb Agglomerationen 2012": 261,
  "Ortschaftsname": "Aeugst am Albis",
  "Arbeitsmarktregionen 2000 (2)": 10,
  "Gemeinde-typen\n(22 Typen) 2000 (1)": 11,
  "Städtische / Ländliche Gebiete 2000 (1)": 2,
  "Grossregionen": 4,
  "Gemeindename": "Aeugst am Albis",
  "MS-Regionen (2)": 4,
  "Touris-mus Regionen 2017": 3,
  "DEGURBA 2011 eurostat": 3
},
{....}
}
```

What is the easiest way to join them on a key *PLZ* from plz.js and *billing_address_zip_code* from orders_play_around.json?
I could load it into JSON file without any problems:

```
plz_data=open('plz.js').read()
plz = json.loads(plz_data)
```

Sorry for the long message. But hopefully, someone can help me with this easy problem. The goal would be to plot it on a map or on a graph, where I can see which PLZ (zipcode) has the most orders.

Comment: Are the curly braces one after the other, immediately, in one giant line? No spaces in between? Is changing the file via another tool like SED an option, or Python only?

Comment: Yes, it is in one giant file, no space in between. If it would be a small file, I would just search+replace "}{" with "},{" to have a standard JSON. But as it is a giant file, I'd like to use some cloud power and use Python (pandas, etc.).
But I will try with SED, maybe that could work as well. Would you use SED for huge files?

Comment: Definitely, I'll post it as answer - if it works let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention turning your file to proper JSON is your initial goal, and you don't mind `sed`, try:

```
sed 's|}{|}\n{|g' originalfile > result
```

Note I added in newlines, not commas. Probably better for your future editing. You can use the `-i` flag so `sed` edits in place, but this is safer. If you really want to use Python it's not a big deal with standard Python. Safest is to read character by character:

```
with open("originalfile") as fd:
    while True:
        ch=fd.read(1)
        if not ch: break
        if ch =="{": print("\n")
        print(ch,end="")
```

or just replace and print (never tested limits of Python, I'm guessing this will work:

```
print(open("originalfile").read().replace("}{","}\n{"))
```

no need for `regex` for this - It's a bit of overkill. Once this is a proper `Json` file it will be easier to use, including loading `Json` through `pandas.read_json`.

Comment: Thank you so much. SED: Somehow it only worked when I used the `sed 's|}{|},  {|g' orders_play_around.json > result.txt` that it created a new line, \n didn't work on my mac os. Regarding JSON load I write another answer.

Comment: @sspaeti your welcome. No need to say thank you though - accept the answer so everyone see it's resolved, and upvote if you want to say an extra thanks.

Comment: perfect I did already  Just added a follow-up, how to join two data-sets based on keys. Hope to get some help, otherwise, I will accept the answer and close question.

Comment: @sspaeti You're probably looking for [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). That warrants another question, but I'm sure it's been asked (how to merge to dataframes in Pandas). Please don't change the question as you go - close this one, do some more research, and if you're stuck then post a new question. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.

```
data = []
with open("originalfile") as fp:
    for l in fp:
        clean_line = ([x.replace("{","").replace("}\n","").replace("\"","") for x in l.split(",")])
        data.append(clean_line)
```

Then you can convert the data list into a pandas dataframe and export to JSON.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
df.to_json()
```

If you want to remove the text, e.g. "billing_address_zip_code", and keep only data, then you can do

```
data = []
with open(filepath) as fp:
    for l in fp:
        splitted = ([x.split(":")[1] for x in l.split(",")])
        data.append(([x.replace("}\n","").replace("\"","") for x in splitted]))
```